# Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: android, react-native

MacBook-Air mlaapp % npx react-native run-android
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-video: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video#readme
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1232 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:631:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:649:15)
at runOnAllDevices (/Users/varmabiraju/projects/Joshi/MyProjects/mlaapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at buildAndRun (/Users/varmabiraju/projects/Joshi/MyProjects/mlaapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:179:41)
at /Users/varmabiraju/projects/Joshi/MyProjects/mlaapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:133:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/varmabraju/projects/Joshi/MyProjects/mlaapp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:182:9)
```

Comment: can you please help me i can't able to run my app in android physical device

Comment: what `gradle` version did you use?

Comment: gradle  version 6.3

Comment: i see. for clarification, can you share your `gradle-wrapper.properties` above?

Comment: distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

Comment: I think you got the wrong file. It should display the gradle version used. Also, please update your question with the properties instead of putting it as a comment. There is space in the question for you to add the information.

Comment: @JoshiG hey, did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing sdk versions in `/android/build.gradle`

```
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
```

Comment: they are already equal to 30. whats next?

Answer (score 0):

from the comments, it seems that you are not using the `gradle` version 6.3. can you update your android build to use `gradle` 6.3 and see if the issue still persists?

another user faced a similar issue and reported this on github. you may want to take a closer look at it [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10248#issuecomment-606322817).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Open task manager (of your OS) and kill adb.exe process. Now start adb again, now adb should start normally.

Answer (score -1):

If this is your error

[error for nativeDevServerPort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2La2.jpg)

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

gradle 6.2 all zip causing this error for run-android please change or upgrade the distributionUrl version of gradle in

gradle-wrapper.properties to

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip

Hope this could help you in installing your react-native application in android